# Адаптация под мобильное устройство с разрешением экрана как у ПК

Tags: css, flexbox, width, media

Народ, всем привет, кто нашел время и желание отозваться!
Сделал адаптацию сайта под различные устройства через @media min-width и max-width (от 0 до 560px) - для мобил, (от 560 до 1280px) - для планшетов. На локальном сервере, как обычно, все четенько! В реальной же сети всё, само собой, совершенно иначе оказалось. А именно, на мобильном загружается версия по умолчанию( для пк).
И все потому, что на телефонах таких как, например, iphone 7 plus или mi max 2 и т.д. разрешение экрана 1080*1920!! Я уверен что проблему можно решить каким-то довольно простым способом, не прибегая к отдельной версии для моб с переадресацией и т.п.

Кто знает как такой ситуации грамотно решить проблему, пожалуйста, отзовитесь!!

Comment: Добавьте в <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Спасибо! Все случилось!